# Изменение элемента списка при наведении на ссылку вне списка

Tags: html, css, hover

Есть ссылка, ниже список.

```
<a class="topPage" href="#">Page 1</a>
<ul class="subMenu">
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 1</li>
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 2</li>
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 3</li>
</ul>
```

Как менять к примеру цвет Текста `UndPage` при наведении на ссылку `Page1`?
 Получается только с соседними элементами.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* для всех */
.topPage:hover+.subMenu li {
  color: green;
}

/* для 1 */
.topPage:hover+.subMenu li:nth-child(1) {
    /*color: red;*/
}

/* для 2 */
.topPage:hover+.subMenu li:nth-child(2) {
    /*color: blue;*/
}

/* для 3 */
.topPage:hover+.subMenu li:nth-child(3) {
    /*color: orange;*/
}
```

```html
<a class="topPage" href="#">Page 1</a>
<ul class="subMenu">
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 1</li>
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 2</li>
  <li class="subLi">UndPage 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: это если рядом. а мне надо наводить на блок вверху а цвет менять через 2 картинки ниже

Answer (score 0):

```css
.eventdependent:hover + .dependent li{
color:#07a;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="eventdependent">Наведи!</a>
<ul class="dependent">
  <li>Тут что-то
  <li>Тут что-то тоже
  <li>Конец списка
</ul>
```

Comment: это если рядом. а мне надо наводить на блок вверху а цвет менять через 2 картинки ниже